# Framework for JAVA socket server application

Tags: java, android, sockets, frameworks, server

I'm developing an `Android` app using a server side for computations and message handling. I need to work with push notifications, so I decided to go with `Socket` and `ServerSocket`.

For now, my server side is just a pure `JAVA` code that receive requests and open sockets accordingly. Is there any framework for my purpose? And how should I run my server side app on a remote server, should I create a `runnable jar` or is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Apache MINA](http://mina.apache.org/mina-project/index.html), which is a socket framework with useful features like NIO, session management, SSL and other filter support.

Using a reliable framework means you spend less time writing boilerplate code.

Yes, you can create a runnable jar and create a bat/sh script to run on your server. Read [this article](https://netbeans.org/kb/articles/javase-deploy.html) for more information on packaging applications.